# JMeter JMS: Getting Error: Failed to connect via SSL to [ssl://<server-name>:7352]: Received fatal alert: protocol_version

Tags: ssl, java-8, jmeter, jms, tls1.2

I'm trying to publish message to a Tibco Queue on a SSL Tibco Server through JMeter 5.4.1 using JMS Point-to-Point Logic Controller.

[JMS Point To Point Controller Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay4dM.png)

But I'm getting the following error message:

> 2021-06-13 12:25:46,278 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JMSSampler: Not permitted:
> Failed to connect to any server at: ssl://[server-name]:7352,
> ssl://[server-name]:7352 [**Error: Failed to connect via SSL to
> [ssl://[server-name]:7352]: Received fatal alert:
> protocol_version:** url that returned this exception =
> SSL://[server-name]:7352 ]
> javax.naming.AuthenticationException: Not permitted: Failed to connect
> to any server at: ssl://[server-name]:7352,
> ssl://[server-name]:7352 [Error: Failed to connect via SSL to
> [ssl://[server-name]:7352]: Received fatal alert:
> protocol_version: url that returned this exception =
> SSL://[server-name] ]     at
> com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsContext.lookup(TibjmsContext.java:670)
> ~[tibjms.jar:8.0.0]   at
> com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsContext.lookup(TibjmsContext.java:491)
> ~[tibjms.jar:8.0.0]   at
> javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
> ~[?:1.8.0_291]    at
> org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.JMSSampler.threadStarted(JMSSampler.java:638)
> [ApacheJMeter_jms.jar:5.4.1]  at
> org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:784)
> [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]     at
> org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:993)
> [jorphan.jar:5.4.1]   at
> org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:976)
> [jorphan.jar:5.4.1]   at
> org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:752)
> [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]     at
> org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:740)
> [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]     at
> org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:252)
> [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]

I tried:
openssl s_client -connect [server-name]:7352

It gave the following output:

> SSL-Session:
> Protocol  : TLSv1.2
> Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
> Session-ID:
> Session-ID-ctx:

So added the following line in jmeter.properties file.

> https.default.protocol=TLSv1.2

Also commented jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms from java.security file for JDK (I'm using jdk1.8.0_291)

```
#    jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, \
#    DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, \
#    include jdk.disabled.namedCurves
```

But still I'm getting the same error. Someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using the wrong property (not only the wrong property but the wrong place as well), you're setting default protocol for [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https), while you need to set it for [TLS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Transport_Layer_Security), i.e. add the next line to ***system.properties*** file

```
jdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

JMeter restart will be required to apply this property.

If it won't help or you will get different errors - consider adding the next line there as well:

```
javax.net.debug=all
```

and then check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) and [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)) for any suspicious entries

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Hi Dimitri....thanks for the reply.
But actually, the issue was with tibjms.jar. The Tibco server was upgraded some hrs before I reported the issue. After changing to latest tibjms.jar in the lib folder in JMeter, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by using the latest tibjms.jar in the lib directory in JMeter as the Tibco server was upgraded some hours before I raised this issue.